# How I can create a test function which reicive a specific ammount of ether in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, testing, chai

The function what I want to test is this

```
    function mint(uint256 tokenId) external payable {
        require(msg.value == 0.01 ether, 'Wrong price');
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }
```

and I want to create two functions test, one for test if works when receive the correct amount and other for when the amount is not correct, but I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by using `if..else` conditions.

Eg.

```
    function mint(uint256 tokenId) external payable {
      if(msg.value == 0.01 ether){
         require(msg.value == 0.01 ether, 'Wrong price');
         _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
      } else {
        // if value received is not 0.01 ether
      }
    }
```